# What's with the happy-place tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just saw this tag: [happy-place](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/happy-place). I've never heard of "happy place" before, and I googled it and couldn't find anything. Should it even be a tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in [another question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1773/3267) inspired by this tag, I don't see it as necessary or helpful, so I removed it from the two questions it was on. If anyone would like to come to its defence, please bring it up in this discussion (and comment to let me know). Unless it is (re-)added to a question by then, it will disappear within 24 hours.

Answer (score 3):

The tag wiki explains that this is a Harry Potter concept. Even if HP is one of the biggest subjects on this site, this is an extremely specialized tag. Are people really going to subscribe to, ignore or search on this tag (which will only make sense on [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) questions)? I'm in favor of removing it, but could be swayed by arguments defending it.

Comment: the other thing is, I could find no other reference to the tag other than on this site: so I'm not sure if it even means.

Comment: The only way a Patronus can be conjured is if the spell caster draws a happy thought from their innermost positive feelings, such as joy or hope. I agree it is a highly obscure tag, and concede it may be a candidate for tag editing or removal.

Comment: After seeing another question about it, I removed it from the two questions it was on.

Comment: Feel free to delete, edit, or rename the Happy-Place tag.